# How to specificy a specific sub webpage in the manifest for chrome web extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My manifest looks like this:

```
 {
      "js": ["JS/jquery.min.js","checkUser.js"],
      "matches": ["https://www.instagram.com/*/"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
  }
```

However, checkUser.js is always running when I'm on any sub page. I want to it to be running when it is having only one placeholder between the two slashes, such as "https://www.instagram.com/user1/", "https://www.instagram.com/user2/" and so on. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Instagram is a SPA so the page is initialized just once, subsequent navigation is faked via pushState. It means that content scripts can run only once. You need to observe changes of the URL, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by using `exclude_globs` by reading [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) site.